# How to remove space between table and <hr>?

Tags: html, css

In html, I have a Table and then a hr tag. There is a gap between table and horizontal line. How can I remove this gap?

Below is a sample code -

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body >
<table border="1" width="100%" >
<tr>
    <td rowspan="2" align="left">a</td>
    <td align="right">c</td>
</tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="right">d</td>
</tr>
</table>
<hr width="100%">
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks, 
Kartic

Comment: What browser(s)? Show a screenshot of what you mean.

Comment: hr {
  margin-top: -10px;
}
Oh, yeah, don't use "hr"

Comment: Don't use `width`, `align`... Use CSS instead.

Comment: DEAR ANSWERING PEOPLE, stop encouraging this! table with border=1... hr... width=100%... this should not be exposed to people nowadays

Comment: `<hr>` in HTML5 doesn't even mean `horizontal rule` anymore, it means [`a thematic break between paragraph`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/hr).

Comment: @rid, I don't mind, please answer if you want, I would still recommend to think twice before answering a question that already includes wrong approach.

Comment: Hi All, I am actually using css. Just to demonstrate what I mean, I have created this sample HTML.

Comment: @rid, I don't think it's a good point. If a person asks on SO for a best way to commit suicide - you will not help, right?

Comment: @mishik - Well that question is very likely to be closed very soon. :P

Comment: @Kartic if you get your answer then please mark as right answer.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, because I'm developing an app that's currently still stuck in Qt 5.7 and the rich-text-format table borders don't work there as I need them to, so I'm stuck with `<hr>` as a delimiter. So, thanks for asking this question. Unfortunately, Qt 5.7 doesn't honor the "margin" attribute in the provided answer anyway, but contrary to the ignorants @mishik @Derek 朕會功夫, (from 2013), I find that the questions about outdated tech have their use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this'

```
<hr width="100%" style="margin-top:0;">
```

Comment: Thanks Sangam for your answer. It's exactly what I wanted